# JsonPath Removing Object from a complete object

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have one jsonArray and with subIds  and details  , out of this Jsonarray there is one primary subId i know , so i want to remove the object of that primary Id from the complete Json using JsonPath

Algo : Known subId : 154
1. Get the primary Json from the Complete Json
2. Remove the primary Json from Complete Json

I got 2 jsonarray from jsonpath as below

completeArray

```
[{
    "d1": "a1",
    "d2": "a2",
    "subId" : 123
}, {
    "d3": "a3",
    "d4": "a4"
    "subId" : 154
}]
```

primaryArray

```
[{
    "d3": "a3",
    "d4": "a4",
    "subId" : 154
}]
```

Desired output

completeArray - PrimaryArray

```
[{
    "d1": "a1",
    "d2": "a2",
    "subId" : 154

}]
```

I tried doing  the same using inbuild function  , `completeArray.remove(PrimaryArray)` but it did nothing 
please note  the JsonArray Returned by Jsonpath is net.minidev.json.JSONArray  , how can i achieve this?

Comment: please add the code you tried

Comment: and please note that `primaryArray` is himself a collection , so to remove from one collection the items in another collection you have to use `removeAll`

Comment: thanks , using removeall its done